# Handling classes on Multiple forms with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a site with mutliple forms, and I would like to, for a specific form, loop through and manipulate the classes on divs and inputs.
I can get the form id with -

```
var thisForm = $(el).closest('form');
var myId = thisForm[0].id
```

But then I am not sure how to loop through specific classes.

---

**Example:**

for each input with "**class1**" I want to change it to "**class2**"

and

for each div with "**class3**" I want to add "**class4**"

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as simple as this

```
var thisForm = $(el).closest('form');
$('input.class1', thisForm).removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');
$('div.class3', thisForm).addClass('class4');
```

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/dXrN8/2

It's jQuery, so you don't need to loop to do these things, actions happen on everything your selector matches.

What we are doing is finding the form, and assigning it to `thisForm`.

Then use that to scope our selectors in the next two lines.

Then select all `input.class1` elements and remove class1 and add class2.

Then select all our `div.class3` elements and add class4.

Comment: blesses to jQuery.. u saved damn lots of time with it.. +1